# Groovy's Getter and Setter shortcut notation incorrectly overriding function call

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm using the update4j API within a `build.gradle` file and when calling the function `Configuration.builder().launcher()` it looks like Groovy's Getter and Setter shortcut notation is incorrectly overriding the function call with a call to `getLauncher()`.

How should I be calling the `launcher()` method instead?

Relevant API docs:

- [Configuration](http://docs.update4j.org/javadoc/update4j/org.update4j/org/update4j/Configuration.html)
- [Configuration.Builder](http://docs.update4j.org/javadoc/update4j/org.update4j/org/update4j/Configuration.Builder.html)

```
Tasks.register('MyTask') {
    Configuration.Builder update4jBuilder =  = Configuration.builder().launcher("com")
    println update4jBuilder.launcher
}

Execution failed for task ':MyTask'.
> No signature of method: org.update4j.Configuration$Builder.launcher?() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [com]
  Possible solutions: launcher(java.lang.String), launcher(java.lang.Class), getLauncher()
```

I haven't seen this affect other function calls like `Configuration.builder().files()` or `Configuration.builder().basePath()`:

```
Tasks.register('MyTask') {
    Configuration.Builder update4jBuilder = Configuration.builder().basePath("${System.properties.'user.home'}${System.properties.'file.separator'}.update4j")
    println update4jBuilder.basePath
}

> Task :MyTask
C:\Users\Kyle\.update4j
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I created a minimal example by putting your code in a `build.gradle` and adding a `buildscript` block to load the library as well as the necessary import for `org.update4j.Configuration`. Then I fixed the wrong casing of `Tasks.register` (`tasks.register`) and the double `=`. Now it works fine for both `basePath` and `launcher`. Could you post your complete `build.gradle` and add the version of Gradle you are using?

Answer (score 0):

@LukasKörfer
There was a special character in between launcher and () that was only seen when pasting the build.gradle in pastebin and were invisible in VSCode

Fixing it there and then copying it back into VSCode fixed it.

Comment: This happened because I copied method names from some JavaDocs

Comment: FYI Groovy does not translate `.launcher()` into `.getLauncher()` and never did... it would translate only property-syntax, like `.launcher` (no parens) into `.getLauncher()` if the getter existed.